# Scrape Javascript files from web page using chrome extension

Tags: javascript, json, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape javascript function calls from an extension and trying it to save in JSON, now I wrote this to see how many javascript files are there in the domain. Next how to select each javascript file and scrape function calls and variable using chrome extension.

```
window.addEventListener('load',function(){

  // Page loaded. Fetch all the scripts
  let all_scripts = document.querySelectorAll('script');
  for(let i =0;i<all_scripts.length;i++){
    if (all_scripts[i].src)
      console.log("Detected script: "+all_scripts[i].src);
    else
      console.log("Detected local script with inline execution");
  }
});
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Next how to select each javascript file and scrape function calls and variable using chrome extension.

Comment: "select each javascript file and scrape function calls and variable" - what does this even mean?

Comment: @wOxxOm Each domain will have multiple JS files. In that case, I want to scrape all the JS files. for example, www.domain.com has 3javascript files. domain.com/sript1.js, script2.js, and script3.js from above code I am able to get the JS files in a domain now need to scrape each JS files and get functions to JSON.

Comment: Neither "scrape functions" nor "get functions" makes sense to me. It's also not possible in general without using a proper JavaScript AST parser like those used in Babel or linters.